# Integrating factor with $-\ln x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln |x| + C$$

however I have seen differential equation notes and solutions claim that the integrating factor for $P(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ is

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=e^{-\ln|x|}=\frac{1}{x}$$

For example consider the IVP

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=xe^x, ~~~y(1)=e^{-1}$$

We have that $P(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ so we could find the integrating factor exactly as above

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=e^{-\ln|x|}=\frac{1}{x}\tag{1a}$$

then our equation would become

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x^2}=e^x \implies \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{1}{x}y\Big)=e^x$$

which after integrating produces

$$\frac{y}{x}=e^x+C$$

Applying the initial condition of $y(1)=e^{-1}$ forms $C=-1$. Then

$$\frac{y}{x}=e^x+1$$

or

$$y=xe^x+x\tag{1b}$$

If instead we found the integrating factor as

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\int\frac{1}{x}dx}=e^{-\ln|x|}=\frac{1}{|x|}\tag{2a}$$

then we would carry through the $|x|$ throughout the computation. We have

$$\frac{1}{|x|}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x|x|}=e^x \implies \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{1}{|x|}y\Big)=e^x$$

which after integrating forms

$$\frac{y}{|x|}=e^x+C$$

Applying the initial condition of $y(1)=e^{-1}$ once again forms $C=-1$. Then

$$\frac{y}{|x|}=e^x+1$$

or

$$y=|x|e^x+|x|\tag{2b}$$

I have seen different people claim that both solutions are correct. I'm not sure if we can drop the absolute value sign at some point in the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation breaks down at $x=0$, so what happens for negative $x$ is something we cannot tell from the given information. We only care about positive $x$ because we *can* only care about positive $x$, and therefore the absolute value signs do nothing.

Even for the simpler differential equation $y'=\frac yx$, we get general solution
$$
y(x)=\cases{ax& for $x>0$\\bx& for $x<0$}
$$
In fact, the true antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is
$$
\cases{\ln x+c_1& for $x>0$\\\ln(-x)+c_2 & for $x<0$}
$$
and you don't have any information to help you pin down $c_2$ (or really $c_2-c_1$) for your integrating factor, which is another manifestation of our inability to tell what happens for negative $x$.

Of course, assuming something like $y$ being differentiable at $x=0$ (if that's even something that can happen; that's not the case with all differential equations) will be enough to stitch together the negative and positive branches.

Comment: The natural question then arises: What if the original equation was, for example, $xy'=y$ instead, which is perfectly fine at $x=0$ and implies that $y'$ should be defined at $0$, though it may be anything. Then dividing both sides by $x$ requires careful consideration.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Your augmented equation carries an implicit assumption that $y$ is differentiable _everywhere_ (at least where it's defined), while the original one doesn't. The relevant domain and assumptions should, of course, have been clarified explicitly from the start. If we are told that $y$ is differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$, the equations $y'=y/x$ and $y'x=y$ are equivalent.

Comment: I generally presume that if no more information is stated, a differential equation is meant to hold on the largest domain it can be uniquely defined containing the initial value(s).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's what I mean by this "implicit assumption". Most people do what you do, and it's a reasonable thing to do, but in an ideal world it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the integrating factor without logarithms.  Use the quotient rule for differentiation:

$\dfrac{(u/v)}{dx}=\dfrac{v(du/dx)-u(dv/dx)}{v^2}$

Put $u=y, v=x$ to get

$\dfrac{d(y/x)}{dx}=\dfrac{x(dy/dx)-y(dx/dx)}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{d(y/x)}{dx}$

which gives the integrating factor and the exact integral in one blow.  Since this applies for both positive and negative $x$ we have the $(1b)$ solution unambiguously.

Comment: What is the difference in the notation 

$$\dfrac{(y/x)}{dx}, ~~\dfrac{d(y/x)}{dx}$$

I would interpret the quotient rule for differentiation as

$$\dfrac{d(y/x)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)=\dfrac{x(dy/dx)-y(dx/dx)}{x^2}$$

Comment: Typo.  Should be corrected.